# Upgrading from Tastypie 0.9.11 to 0.11 put_detail

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Code that worked in api.py With Python 2.6, Django 1.4.1, Tastypie 0.9.11 (Running on 2.6.32-48-generic-pae #110-Ubuntu SMP) Does not work with Python 2.6, Django 1.5, Tastypie 0.11 (Running on Centos 5)

```
    def hydrate_bus_location(self, bundle):
         # Guard against the method being called twice
         if not hasattr(bundle, 'geopoint_processed'):
            lon = bundle.data['bus_location'][0] / 1e6
            lat = bundle.data['bus_location'][1] / 1e6
            bundle.data['bus_location'] = Point(lon, lat)
           bundle.geopoint_processed = True
         return bundle

    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
        deserialized = self.alter_deserialized_detail_data(request, deserialized)
        bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(deserialized), request=request)

        try:
            drive = Drive.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
            bundle = self.hydrate_bus_location(bundle)
            drive.bus_location = bundle.data['bus_location']
            drive.save()
            return http.HttpNoContent()
        except:
            return http.HttpBadRequest()
```

changed to

```
    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.body,
```

More Code:

```
    def alter_deserialized_list_data(self, request, data):
      location = data.get('location')
      if location:
        lon = data['location'][0] / 1e6
        lat = data['location'][1] / 1e6
        location = Point(lon, lat)
      else:
        drive_stop = DriveStop.objects.select_related('stop__stop_address').get(id=data['drivestop_id'])
        location = drive_stop.stop.stop_address.geopoint
      bus_entry_exits = []
      for patron in data['patrons']:
        date_and_time = "{0} {1}".format(data['date'], patron['time'])
        date_and_time = datetime.strptime(date_and_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        bus_entry_exit = {
            'location': location,
            'datetime': date_and_time,
            'drive_stop_id': data['drivestop_id'],
            'patron_id': patron['id'],
            'entry_exit_type': patron['action']
         }
        bus_entry_exits.append(bus_entry_exit)
      return bus_entry_exits
```

Get response:

```
    curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "user:pass" -X POST  https://api.server.com/api/full/busentryexit/ -d "{\"drivestop_id\":74627,\"date\":\"2014-04-24\",\"location\":[-86895029,41707539],\"patrons\":{\"action\":\"Entry\",\"id\":1323177,\"time\":\"17:03:47\"}}"
    HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
    Date: Tue, 20 May 2014 20:23:57 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Connection: close
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: application/json
```

Get error:

```
    {"error_message": "string indices must be integers", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 426, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/django_projects/pats/src/routes/api.py\", line 343, in post_list\n    deserialized = self.alter_deserialized_list_data(request, deserialized)\n\n  File \"/home/django_projects/pats/src/routes/api.py\", line 363, in alter_deserialized_list_data\n    date_and_time = \"{0} {1}\".format(data['date'],patron['time'])\n\nTypeError: string indices must be integers\n"}
```

Comment: Needed to change date_and_time = "{0} {1}".format(data['date'], patron['time'])   to  date_and_time = "{0} {1}".format(data.get('date'), patron['time']) ... still have problem with getting time ... data['patrons'] is {u'action': u'Entry', u'id': 1323177, u'time': u'17:03:47'}

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing:

```
      curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "user:pass" -X POST api.server.com/api/full/busentryexit -d "{\"drivestop_id\":74627,\"date\":\"2014-04-24\",\"location\":[-86895029,4170753‌​9],\"patrons\":[{\"action\":\"Entry\",\"id\":1323177,\"time\":\"17:03:47\"},{\"ac‌​tion\":\"Exit\",\"id\":1323177,\"time\":\"18:03:47\"}]}"
      HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED 
      Date: Wed, 21 May 2014 07:03:18 GMT 
      Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Vary: 
      Accept X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN –
```